# fade in and scale down a div on pageload

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make these 4 divs fade in one after the next, which is working fine but I want to add a zoom effect to it also, from big down to its normal size. here is my code so far. any advice?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $('.color1').hide().fadeIn(500).animate({scale: '-=.1'}, 1000);  
     $('.color2').hide().fadeIn(1000).animate({scale: '-=.1'}, 1000); 
    $('.color3').hide().fadeIn(1500).animate({scale: '-=.1'}, 1000); 
     $('.color4').hide().fadeIn(2000).animate({scale: '-=.1'}, 1000); 
</script>
<div class="logoDot color1"></div>
<div class="logoDot color2"></div>
<div class="logoDot color3"></div>
<div class="logoDot color4"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this:

```
// Configure initial parameters
var from = {height: 100, width: 100};
var to = {opacity: 1, height: 30, width: 30};

$('.color1').css(from).animate(to, 500);
$('.color2').css(from).animate(to, 1000);
$('.color3').css(from).animate(to, 1500); 
$('.color4').css(from).animate(to, 2000);
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/54pgp/1/

Answer (score 1):

You don't really need a lot of jQuery to do this you can use CSS transitions to scale both opacity and scale. I have added spans around your text to make sure only the text scales and not the element.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/4PBSY/)**

The transition is triggered when the scale class is removed.

The CSS

```
.logoDot span.scale {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
    transform: scale(1.5);
    opacity: 0;
}

.logoDot span {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    display: inline-block; 
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

.color1 span {        
    -webkit-transition-delay: .5s;
    -moz-transition-delay: .5s;
    -o-transition-delay: .5s;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}

.color2 span {        
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.color3 span {        
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1.5s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1.5s;
    -o-transition-delay: 1.5s;
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}

.color4 span {        
    -webkit-transition-delay: 2s;
    -moz-transition-delay: 2s;
    -o-transition-delay: 2s;
    transition-delay: 2s;
}
```

The HTML

```
<div class="logoDot color1">
    <span class="scale">Test 1</span>
</div>
<div class="logoDot color2">
    <span class="scale">Test 2</span>
</div>
<div class="logoDot color3">
    <span class="scale">Test 3</span>
</div>
<div class="logoDot color4">
    <span class="scale">Test 4</span>
</div>
```

Triggering the animation

```
$('span').removeClass("scale")
```